# Decimal Precision in C#

Tags: precision, decimalformat

```
double a=0;
double b=20;
double c=a/b;
```

This code gives c as 0 but I want it as 0.xxxxxx.

Not as string as I want to perform further calculations based on the value.

Comment: I'm a little confused, because the answer *is* zero. It's not converting it to an integer or rounding it (more than any other calculation with floating point numbers). Can you clarify some more about what you want, and what's not working now?

Comment: Do you realize that the double value 0.000000 **is** the double value 0? The thing that you are asking for is the thing that you already have.

Comment: If you want to round the number to a particular number of decimal places you can use [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want to *display* a particular number of decimal places, say six, you can use `c.ToString("N6")`: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).